# Convert timestamps to milliseconds - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, timestamp

I have a bunch of files with timestamps associated with x and y coordinates. Currently the format of the timestamps is the following:

**2016-11-08T15:55:01.7802880+00:00**

I need to convert these into manipulatable format, as for example in milliseconds using matlab. I do not wan´t to extract only the milliseconds in the timestamps (example: .780), I need the **absolute duration in milliseconds**.

Thanks in advance!

Cheers

Comment: See: [`datetime`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/datetime.html#buhzxmk-13)

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out!

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there's a way to convert it with Matlab functions, but I've used this for the past little while. 
Gets the job done.

[ISO8601toserial.m File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39389-iso-8601-date-string-to-serial-date-number)

Comment: Thanks I'l try this out!